# Is 12:00:01 AM a valid time?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlanywhere

I use SQL Anywhere Database. When I add one second to 00:00:00, it becomes 12:00:01 AM. In my C++ code end, it crashes saying it's an invalid time.

```
select top 1 DATEPART(HOUR, trans ),trans, DATEADD(second, 1, trans ),CAST('2015-01-01 00:00:01' AS DATETIME) AS LedgerDateTime from pay
```

[image]

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: convert your time in `12 hour` format.

Comment: because your c++ code is broken?

Comment: @DarkRob, Actually, the result was showed in a third party tool. Maybe it's the tool's problem.

Comment: 00:00:00 is 24 hours format. 12:00:01 is 12 hours format. Don’t mix formats.

Comment: @ZDF, I didn't mix them up. It's the sql tool showing the time in 12 format. And I think 12:00:01 AM is not a valid time.

Comment: @ZDF, I think 00:00:01 in 12 hours format, it should be 00:00:01 AM, not 12:00:01 AM.

Comment: @AnthonySottile, Actually, I just called an ATL read ODBC dataset API. This code works with other columns and other values of this column.

Comment: _"I think 00:00:01 in 12 hours format"_ See [24h clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock)

Answer (score -1):

OK, I looked up.

`12:00:01 AM` is a valid time.

The reason for the crash maybe because of the lacking of memory.

[image]

The data volumn is too big for my computer.